# How to disable user interaction with superview unless subview is removed?

Tags: ios, uiview, superview

I have a view loading multiple subviews and subviews loading within the subview. 
I want to disable user interaction with all views except last loaded subview.
Please help ,Thanks

Comment: You can try UIView's opaque property. Set yourView.opaque = YES;

Comment: Once you disable interaction for Parent all the respective subviews also get disable. Please elaborate what you want to know.